How can I ensure memory is allocated near an address?
I am writing a JIT recompiler for x86_64, and at times the emitted code needs to call a function from the compiled binary.
Due to ASLR, the .text segment of my program is placed at some random address.
Can I allocate my JIT's code cache of 32 MiB in such a way where its address is always close enough to the .text segment that I can safely emit relative calls instead of absolute calls? I am in Linux.

i would avoid depending on relative calls like that

What do you mean by "depending on relative calls"? There's no dependency here, I can do absolute calls just fine. I'm asking if there's a way to optimize these calls to a single instruction rather than two. For example, marking the code buffer as static should usually place it close to code. Could you elaborate?

I’d look up a vtable or jump table implementation https://guihao-liang.github.io/2020/05/30/what-is-vtable-in-cpp

Possible duplicates: Custom heap/memory allocation ranges, How to malloc in address range > 4 GiB, Allocate at low memory address

@DanielA.White: Why would you do that much indirection when you just want to emit a call to a specific statically-compiled C function that doesn't need polymorphism?  At worst you'd want call [rel32] with some static data near the JIT code (in the same allocation), or mov rax, imm64 / call rax, as in Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code

Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code suggests putting your 32-MiB array in the BSS so it's definitely within +-2GiB of other static code/data in the same executable or library, and using mprotect to make it executable.  Or other tricks like MMAP_32BIT if you're making a non-PIE executable.  Potential duplicate of that.

Near duplicate: Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code - my answer suggests allocating nearby to enable jmp/call rel32, and suggests some ways to do that.
One good method to do that is to use an array in the BSS, instead of dynamically allocating.  Since you have a known size limit that's not huge (32 MiB) for your JIT region, that's perfect.
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdalign.h>  // for alignas instead of _Alignas, if you're not using C23

// page aligned to make sure it doesn't share a page with anything else
// And for easy use of mprotect (or Windows VirtualProtect)
alignas(4096) unsigned char JIT_buf[32ULL * 1024*1024];

void jit_init(){
   // 31 MiB of code, for example, leaving 1 MiB of data READ|WRITE without exec
   mprotect(JIT_buf, 31ULL * 1024*1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);
}

In the standard code models for x86-64, all static code+data for an executable or shared object is within +-2GiB of each other, making anywhere reachable from anywhere with rel32 addressing.  In the non-PIE code model, it goes in the low 2GiB of virtual addresss-space (so mmap(MAP_32BIT) would work).  But modern PIE executables and shared libraries get mapped outside the low 2GiB.
If your size isn't so small but has an upper bound below a couple GiB, you might still use an array at the end of the BSS.  Perhaps with __attribute__((section(".bss.jit")) and use a custom linker script if necessary to get that linked at the end of the BSS, if the default one doesn't match all .bss* names.  That avoids hurting dTLB locality for other global variables.  In runs where you never use more than say 100 MiB, it's basically as if the array was only 100 MiB, and the part you use is contiguous with other globals.
Memory you never touch doesn't really cost anything since Linux does overcommit, like from mmap or the BSS.  (It's zeroes lazily by the kernel on first access, in the page fault handler.)

If this is in a shared library, make it static, or __attribute__((hidden)) (perhaps by making that the default), so it's truly in this shared library's BSS, not the main executable's.
If this isn't a shared library, another option is to allocate memory with sbrk, but only if you never use malloc / new, or avoid letting them use sbrk.  That will give you memory near the end of the BSS (of the main executable).  Not quite contiguous: ASLR randomizes the break, but on my system (Linux kernel 6.7.2) the distance from a global variable to an sbrk allocation varies from 1 to 31 MiB (same on Godbolt), which still easily puts it within +-2GiB rel32 range of static code/data.
But this is maybe not as future-proof or portable; future or other current systems could randomly put the break far away from static code/data.  If you do this, you should include a check so you can tell the user to report what system doesn't work the way you expected.
Glibc malloc uses sbrk for small allocations.  According to @zwol on Why using both malloc/calloc/realloc and brk functions will results in undefined behavior? , "The implementation of malloc may assume that no code other than itself calls sbrk with a nonzero argument."  It might for example think it owns all the memory from its last call to the new break, which would include your allocation.  Or more subtle corruption of its bookkeeping.  I don't know for sure that glibc malloc would actually break, but the relevant standards (probably POSIX) doesn't require it to work.
If you tune Glibc malloc to never use brk / sbrk, you'd probably be ok.  By default it only uses mmap for large allocations, so it can give them back to the OS immediately on free, even if other allocations were made in the meantime.  Or use a different malloc library that never uses sbrk at all.  I've heard that glibc's malloc isn't wonderful and third-party mallocs can be more performant for some use-cases.
Note that G++ new/delete internally uses the same allocator as malloc.

As always, don't forget to call __builtin___clear_cache(&JIT_buf[start], &JIT_buf[end]) in GNU C after you store some bytes to it, before you call a function pointer that uses that array as machine code.  On x86 it doesn't actually clear cache, just blocks optimizations like dead-store elimination (example: https://godbolt.org/z/5671x3MYn).  That probably won't be a problem since calling mprotect means a pointer to the buffer has "escaped" into code the optimizer can't see, but it's a good idea to do that between storing code and calling it.  If nothing else, it might ease porting to architectures that do need something in asm (most non-x86).  See How to get c code to execute hex machine code? for more details.

If none of that works, you might put an array of function pointers somewhere in your JIT buffer, as "static" data that code there can access with RIP+rel32 addressing modes like call [rel32].  Or if you pass your functions a register pointing to some address, call [reg+disp8] or call [reg+disp32].
I think (or hope) this is what Daniel A. White was trying to suggest when he mentioned a vtable.  Normal C++ vtables imply multiple levels of indirection starting with a pointer stored in an object.  You don't want that, just an array of function pointers.  The GOT would be a better analogy; call [rip+rel32] with the GOT entry is how library function calls compile with gcc -fno-plt.
Or as a one-off, mov rax, imm64 / call rax always works, but is indeed somewhat less efficient than a direct call.  Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code.  Depending on the surrounding code and how often its run, it might be worse than call [rel32] with a function pointer that has to get loaded as data.  If a couple cache lines of function pointers are frequently used so they stay hot in cache, that's probably better than a 10-byte movabs.
Of course direct call rel32 is always the most efficient; smallest code-size and it has the address available to the front-end earliest in case the BTB didn't predict the existence and destination of the branch before it fully decoded.  (Or for the indirect branches, before it executed.)
It's probably hard to microbenchmark the difference caused by fewer indirect branches to predict, since that will most likely only matter across a whole large program.  Any microbenchmark would have everything predicting perfectly.  Better front-end throughput from direct calls might or might not make a measurable difference, depending on what you're JITing them into.

Like the comments said, it's best not to depend on relative calls.
You can use mmap to request a memory mapping at a certain address. The problem is knowing which addresses are free.
Something like this could work:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char __executable_start[];
extern char __etext[];
extern char _end[];

#define OFFSET (32 * 1024 * 1024)
#define SIZE (32 * 1024 * 1024)

int main()
{
    printf(".text start = %p\n", (void*)__executable_start);
    printf(".text end   = %p\n", (void*)__etext);
    printf("binary end  = %p\n", (void*)_end);
    
    char* buffer = mmap(_end + OFFSET, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    printf("buffer      = %p\n", buffer);
    printf("distance    = %d\n", buffer - __etext);
}

However, it is not guaranteed to work. If the requested region already contains a mapping, the kernel may just ignore your hint (Linux seem to do so, in fact).
If you really want to do this, I suggest you try allocating memory close to .text - if you succeed, you use relative calls or absolute calls otherwise.
A better version of the program above would be:
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char __executable_start[];
extern char __etext[];
extern char _end[];

#define OFFSET (32 * 1024 * 1024)
#define SIZE (32 * 1024 * 1024)
#define MAX_ATTEMPTS 10

int main()
{
    printf(".text start = %p\n", (void*)__executable_start);
    printf(".text end   = %p\n", (void*)__etext);
    printf("end         = %p\n", (void*)_end);
    
    // align to next page
    char* buffer = (char*)(((uintptr_t)_end + 4095) & ~4095);
    int attempts;

    for (attempts = 0; attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS; attempts++)
    {
        char* result = mmap(buffer, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE, -1, 0);
        if (result != MAP_FAILED)
        {
            printf("success at attempt #%d\n", attempts + 1);
            break;
        }
            
        if (errno != EEXIST)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        buffer += OFFSET;
    }

    if (attempts == MAX_ATTEMPTS)
    {
        printf("failed after %d attempts, falling back to absolute instructions\n", attempts);
        buffer = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    }

    printf("buffer      = %p\n", buffer);
    printf("distance    = %d\n", buffer - __etext);
}

Now, we tell the kernel that we want our mapping at an exact address. If a mapping already exists there, we try at another address. If that fails a certain number of times, we can just fall back to absolute instructions.
Alternatively, you could parse /proc/self/maps and find a free region close to .text.
First, however, I would try benchmarking whether absolute calls are actually slower than relative ones. You may not need to care.

If the requested region already contains a mapping, the kernel may just ignore your hint - yes, that's why it's just called a hint.  If you want failure in that case, use the Linux-specific MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE.  (Not MAP_FIXED; in that case it will discard the previous mapping!)  Probably your best bet for the OP's use-case is to put the JIT buffer in the BSS (a static array) and use mprotect to make part of it executable, as in Handling calls to (potentially) far away ahead-of-time compiled functions from JITed code

Allocating with brk would be another way to get memory contiguous with the BSS and thus near everything else.  At least contiguous with the main executable's BSS, which doesn't help if this is a library.

@PeterCordes Using .bss could be a good idea, although the size will then be fixed. brk won't work (I tried) because the program break is often randomized.

Yes, in this case the OP stated their use-case is a fixed-size 32MiB JIT "cache".  In other cases, a "big enough" array that you use part of can work, especially if you can arrange for it to be at the end of your BSS (maybe putting it in a special section) so you don't hurt dTLB locality for global variables.  I hadn't realized the break was randomized to not be contiguous with BSS anymore.  That makes sense for security.

I checked, and on my system (Linux kernel 6.7.2), the distance from an sbrk allocation to a global in the BSS randomly varies from 1 to 31 MiB.  So that's plenty close enough for this use case.  (But thanks for letting me know it's not actually contiguous: interesting).  The problem is actually mixing malloc with sbrk; apparently my optimism was misplaced.  Programs that use malloc will need to use a different malloc implementation that avoids sbrk if they want to use the break.
